# save input from user in a python program

Tags: python

I am writing a program in Python where a user can input information that is saved - even if the program is terminated. How do I implement this?

Comment: Look up `pickle`. It allows you to easily save ('serialize') data of any Python type and later reimport those.

Comment: Yup, this is possible :-) You should probably [edit] your question to include your code; that way more specific advice can be given. In general, though, I would say using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module works quite well for many purposes.

Comment: You can write it to a file, use a database etc etc. There are literally tons of storage options. Just search, pick one and go ahead.

Comment: @roadrunner66 `pickle` has security issues ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26934565/660921)) and I would not advice it unless I'm really sure what it's being used for.

Comment: You should [refer to this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question. That said, what you're actually looking for is a signal handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: To summarize the other answers, in order to save information, look at any modules from the "Data persistence" (the name speaks for itself) in the python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the user to input a string of data, you can use [`raw_input()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output) to get it, and then send it to a file using [`pickle`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) library, as mentioned in comments above.

To use [`pickle`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle), you should before `open` a file in writing mode and then use this file to dump into it your object containing the string.

A secure way to open a file is to use a [`with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/), it will be closed at the end of the statement.

```
import pickle

myData = raw_input('What is your name ? ')

with open("name.p", "wb" ) as myFile:
    pickle.dump(myData, myFile)
```

Later, you can get back the object by opening the pickle file in read mode and store its content in a variable.

```
import pickle

with open("name.p", "rb" ) as myFile:
    myData = pickle.load(myFile)
```